# Increment inside for loop? in r

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to make 1000 simulations to see how many of my *f* values are in the reject region which is above 1.48 and below .67.

I have this but the variables don't increment as they should:

```
for (k in 1:1000){
   Adata = rnorm(100, mean = 30, sd = 10)
   Bdata = rnorm(100, mean = 45, sd = 10)
   f = (sd(Bdata)^2)/(sd(Adata)^2)
   if (f > 1.48){
     a = 0
     a <- a + 1}
   if (f < .67){
     b = 0
     b <- b + 1}
} 

 a
 [1] 1
 b
 [1] 1
```

The end goal is find the sum of *a* and *b*

I have also tried:

```
 for (k in 1000){
   Adata = rnorm(100, mean = 30, sd = 10)
   Bdata = rnorm(100, mean = 45, sd = 10)
   f = (sd(Bdata)^2)/(sd(Adata)^2)
   a = f > 1.48
   b = f < .67
   }
 y = sum(a)+sum(b)
 y
 [1] 0
```

What other way would I increment to get the total amount of *f's* that are in the reject region?

Comment: Try creating global variables instead. It is dirty but it solves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, you are reset-ing `a` and `b` to zero every time that the if statement is true. Therefore, the max value will always be `1`.

To fix, rearrange those lines:

```
a = 0 #initialize outside of the loop
b = 0 #initialize outside of the loop
set.seed(1) # added for SO as you are using rnorm, remove this when you run your simulations
for (k in 1:1000){
   Adata = rnorm(100, mean = 30, sd = 10)
   Bdata = rnorm(100, mean = 45, sd = 10)
   f = (sd(Bdata)^2)/(sd(Adata)^2)
   if (f > 1.48){
     a <- a + 1}
   if (f < .67){
     b <- b + 1}
}
```

I now get a = 13 and b = 29

That said, **don't increment variables like this in R**. You can take advantage of matrices and vectorized operations.

First Create simulation matrices

```
set.seed(1)
Adata = matrix(data = rnorm(100*1000, mean = 30, sd = 10), nrow = 1000, ncol = 100) 
Bdata = matrix(data = rnorm(100*1000, mean = 30, sd = 10), nrow = 1000, ncol = 100)
```

Then calculate your `f` score for each line:

`f <- apply(Bdata,1,function(x){sd(x)^2})/apply(Adata,1,function(x){sd(x)^2})`

now you can simply use:

```
sum(f > 1.48)
[1] 15
```

and:

```
sum(f < .67)
[1] 25
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first block of code you are resetting a and b to 0 every iteration, then possibly adding 1 (so the most they will ever be is 1 because next iteration they will be set to 0 again).

In the second block you are setting a and b to either TRUE or FALSE, but you are overwriting the value, so you only see the value from the final iteration (actually that loop only runs once with k equal to 1000, but if you had 1:1000 there then you would only see the last iteration).

The simple solution is to move the `a=0` and `b=0` (or better `a <- 0` and `b <- 0`) outside of the loop.

The better approach is to use something in the `apply` family of functions.

I would suggest something like:

```
out <- replicate(1000, {
   Adata = rnorm(100, mean = 30, sd = 10)
   Bdata = rnorm(100, mean = 45, sd = 10)
   (sd(Bdata)^2)/(sd(Adata)^2)
  })

sum( out > 1.48 )
sum( out < 0.67 )

sum( out > 1.48 | out < 0.67 )
```